# python use multi thread to read from mongo slow

Tags: python, multithreading, mongodb, pymongo

`Just link the title, when I use multi thread to read the data from mongo, not fast even equal to only one process, is there something wrong i use?`

My multi thread code is just like the following:

```
def multi_thread_flush(logger):
    n_loops = 20
    locks = []
    for i in range(0, n_loops):
        lock = thread.allocate_lock()
        lock.acquire()
        locks.append(lock)
    try:
        for i in range(0, n_loops):
            thread.start_new_thread(get_node_entry_id,
                                (logger, 0 + 400000 * i, 400000, locks[i],))
        for i in range(0, n_loops):
            while locks[i].locked(): pass
        logger.info("[all down] all down")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("exception: %s" % e)

def get_node_entry_id(logger, num1, num2, lock):
    cursor = client.mongo_collection.find({},no_cursor_timeout=True).skip(num1).batch_size(30)
    count = 0
    for item in cursor:
        if count > num2:
            break
        logger.info("%s" % item["_id"])
        count = count + 1
    lock.release()
```

My one process code is like the following:

```
def get_node_entry_id():
    cursor = client.NodeEntry.find({}, no_cursor_timeout=True).batch_size(30)
    for item in cursor:
        print item["_id"]
    client_c.close()
```

I try to change batch_size from 300 to 3000, but improve small.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of mongo.skip() as your batch size is 400000+. Because the server has to walk from the beginning of the collection to the specified offset every time the query is executed. See [this doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/).

> As the offset increases, mongo.skip() will be slower.

It also suggests using index to perform slicing, for example:

> db.col.find({_id: { $gt: offset}}).limit(batch_size)